# azurerm service principle role attachment propagation issue

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I have a service principle (enterprise application), which is granted access into many azure tenants, to allow deploying infrastructure into different azure accounts/subscriptions.

For deploying Azure resource via terraform, I am creating roles for each module. For instance to deploy a Virtual Network, I am creating a role with the necessary permissions. With that, I am running into an issue where on `terraform apply` the role gets created and assigned to the service principle, but then one of the resources fails due to not having permissions. This however is fixed by running another `terraform apply` right after.

Below is a quick example of the issue I am facing, and hope that someone has viable solution. I have tried adding in null resource that waits for 10 minutes, but whether it's 2 seconds or 10 minutes there's always a permissions error. I am unable to use a blanket role like `Contributor` to resolve this issue.

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "1.4.6"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.58.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
    }
  }
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  tenant_id                  = "<tenant_id>" 
  subscription_id            = "<subscription_id>" 
  client_id                  = "<service_principle_id>"
  client_secret              = "<client_secret>"
}

resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vpc_role" {
  name        = "VPCRole"
  description = "Role to deploy and manage VPC + Network"
  scope       = "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>"

  permissions {
    actions = [
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete",
    ]
  }
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vpc_role_assignment" {
  scope                            = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_id               = azurerm_role_definition.vpc_role.role_definition_resource_id
  principal_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id # needs to be object_id or else it comes up identity not found
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true

  depends_on = [ azurerm_role_definition.vpc_role ]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resource-group"
  location = "eastus"

  depends_on = [ azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment ]
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "nat_ip_1" {
  name                = "example-nat-ip-1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "nat_gw_1" {
  name                = "example-nat-gw-1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "ng_ip_1_assoc" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.nat_gw_1.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.nat_ip_1.id
}
```

#### Output

```
Plan: 8 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

azurerm_role_definition.vpc_role: Creating...
azurerm_role_definition.vpc_role: Creation complete after 2s [id=/subscriptions/<sub_id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/eb2c6f71-162e-a62b-5d15-4c4b8a0ba0ee|/subscriptions/<sub_id>]
azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment: Creating...
azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment: Creation complete after 23s [id=/subscriptions/<sub_id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/5d4d4ee3-6822-9af7-66ad-3550dc1ab9c5]
azurerm_resource_group.example: Creating...
╷
│ Error: checking for presence of existing resource group: resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '<client_id>' with object id '<object_id>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourcegroups/example-resource-group' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
│
│   with azurerm_resource_group.example,
│   on main.tf line 72, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example":
│   72: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
│
╵
```

#### Expected Behaviour

The expected behavior is that after role creation -> role assignment, any resources that are dependent on the role being assigned to service principle used within the provider, should be able to deploy resources

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment by executing your code. However, I encountered the issue **intermittently**. Sometimes the error occurred, while other times it did not. To resolve this problem, you need to **allow some time for the resources to be created after assigning the role**. It's possible that the role assignment does not take effect immediately. Therefore, to mitigate this error, I have added a **[time_sleep](https://i.imgur.com/YO9Kxxt.png) terraform resource** after the role assignment. Please find the complete code below..

```json
terraform {
  required_version = "1.4.6"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.58.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
    }
  }
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  tenant_id                  = "" 
  subscription_id            = "" 
  client_id                  = ""
  client_secret              = ""
}

resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vpc_role" {
  name        = "VPCRole03"
  description = "Role to deploy and manage VPC + Network"
  scope       = "/subscriptions/7195d375-7af2-43f1-bd66-12e77ac05818"

  permissions {
    actions = [
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/natGateways/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete",
    ]
  }
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vpc_role_assignment" {
  scope                            = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_id               = azurerm_role_definition.vpc_role.role_definition_resource_id
  principal_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id # needs to be object_id or else it comes up identity not found
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true

  depends_on = [ azurerm_role_definition.vpc_role ]
}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_60_seconds" {
  create_duration = "60s"
  depends_on = [ 
    azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment
    
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resource-group-03"
  location = "eastus"

  depends_on = [ 
    azurerm_role_assignment.vpc_role_assignment,
    time_sleep.wait_60_seconds
    ]
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet-03"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet-03"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "nat_ip_1" {
  name                = "example-nat-ip-1-03"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "nat_gw_1" {
  name                = "example-nat-gw-1-03"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "ng_ip_1_assoc" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.nat_gw_1.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.nat_ip_1.id
}
```

Output:
https://i.imgur.com/c30gSN8.png

Comment: Thanks for the response, and this does seem intermittent for others but unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue. I've stated already having tried setting a `null_resource` with `sleep 60` up to `sleep 500` and the issue persists. If it's not the resource group that causes the error, it's any other resource that follows the resource group creation.

This seems more of an Azure / provider issue with eventual consistency on the service principle and role being attached, or some caching issue on Azure roles maybe?

Comment: @Gorgon_Union, thanks for your reply. Did you try adding the dependent_on to the time_sleep resource and azurerm_resource_group resource as shown above?